# System wide SOCKS5 Proxy

Tags: arch-linux, iptables, ssh-tunneling, socks, route

I connect to my Server on the internet using `ssh -D 3128 user@rootserver.com`. If I am right I thereby open a SOCKS v5 Proxy to my Server. Using Firefox and FoxyProxy I can now add this to my proxys and tunnel my HTTP-Traffic over it. Howsoever I'd like to use this SOCKS Proxy for all my traffic. Friends told me that they've seen this by modifying your route or using `iptables` howsoever I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SOCKS5`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS5) is a protocol (i.e. [in the application layer of OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)), so plain network-routing (e.g. via `iptables`) alone *won't do*. (It's probably necessary, but not sufficient.)

What you need is a [*proxifier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers).  Without having tried it, [`tun2socks`](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks), allowing you to *"socksify TCP at the network layer"*, looks promising (as does [`proxychains`](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/), without `iptables` but prefixing programs explicitly).

(Could `socat` be used here?  [This](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/machine/penguin-lust/src/socat-1.7.1.2/EXAMPLES) mentions `socat` for socksifying, but I'm unsure at the moment.)

Comment: tun2socks in combination with iptables did the job, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**[Proxybound](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/Proxybound)** can do the job

To apply it system widely as you asked you can ad it as a default preloaded library, to do so edit `/etc/ld.so.preload` and add `/usr/local/lib/libproxybound.so` or `libproxybound.so` depending on how you installed proxybound

After reboot any started application will be preloading proxybound and thus proxified

This method need to be **tested carefully** because proxybound is not compatible with all the applications you may encounter (resulting in some applications not starting because proxybound does not allow unsupported apps to start, this is to avoid leaks). Alternatively you can setup the env variable `LD_PRELOAD` with the value `/usr/local/lib/libproxybound.so` for a specific userspace or user session to limit where proxybound is applied.