# How can I setup a SOCKS4 or 5 proxy on CentOS 5.8?

Tags: centos, proxy, socks

I live in Iran and due to its restrict censorship, We all have extreme difficulties accessing normal sites and services. So I thought this would be a great idea to setup a proxy server on my VPS, so that I myself could find a way around this censorship.
Can anyone show me a step by step working tutorial on this matter? Or guide me in the right direction?
I will be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know [`flossmanuals.net`](http://flossmanuals.net/)?  They've got a great manual on [**How to Bypass Internet Censorship**](http://en.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-censorship) (also as [`epub`](http://en.flossmanuals.net/_booki/bypassing-censorship/bypassing-censorship.epub) and [`pdf`](http://en.flossmanuals.net/_booki/bypassing-censorship/bypassing-censorship.pdf) for offline use -- and note the translations, among others in [Farsi](http://www.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-fa)).

Among many tools and methods, they cover [*SOCKS proxies*](http://en.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-censorship/ch038_socks-proxies/). But given a VPS somewhere, the other ways they mention should be considered, too.  (For example [how to use `ssh` to act as a SOCKS server](http://en.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-censorship/ch037_ssh-tunnelling/), or use [OpenVPN](http://en.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-censorship/ch036_openvpn/)).

Beside guiding you through configuring Firefox to use SOCKS for everything (i.e. not forget DNS), they also mention tools to *socksify* any application (we recently had this issue coming up [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44653/11539)).

Do not skip the chapter on [*Circumvention and Safety*](http://en.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-censorship/ch008_chapter-3-safe-circumvention/).

---

In particular, using a machine `myvps` that you can `ssh` into; setting up a local (say, on `laptop`) SOCKS5 Proxy (`laptop --> myvps --> internet`) can be done via running

```
ssh -D 1080 accountname@myvps
```

*on the `laptop`*.  After the connection is established, you can use `127.0.0.1:1080` on `laptop` as a SOCKS5 server.  (I'm referring to OpenSSH here, but PuTTY can do this, via `Connection, SSH, Tunnels` in the configuration.)

In Firefox you can *tunnel all traffic through the SOCKS server* via

- `Preferences - Advanced - Network - Settings...`: set this to manual, *SOCKS host* `127.0.0.1`, port 1080; and
- the `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` setting in `about:config` (just enter this as the URL), set this to *true*.

Comment: :Thank you verymuch. the site you introduced is censored here! but i will find a way to open it ;) Thank you again

Comment: can you please explain more on the ssh -D part? where you said i can easily use that to bypass proxy? i'm clueless

Comment: I hope I clarified the section, did I?  (Btw, does [this](http://bayfiles.com/file/jKsv/gytgdU/bypassing-censorship.pdf) and [this](http://bayfiles.com/file/jKuh/Ecwz4N/bypassing-fa.epub) (use the "Premium" link) work for you?)

Comment: Thank you very much ;) those are great articles ;) thanks a billion again :)